# Is grouping an effective method to factoring?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

In Algebra, I've been taught to factor polynomials by grouping.  Here is an example:

$$x^3-2x^2+x-2=x^2(x-2)+1(x-2)=(x^2+1)(x-2)$$

I'm wondering if this is an effective method because when they give us problems, the grouping tactic is very obvious like above.  But is it good for problems in general that are more than just homework for section 3.7 (just a random number)?

---

IMO, it is not very effective, and methods like rational roots theorem should usually be used over this one.  To me, it seems to be a 'lucky' case that one could use this.

Comment: Your intuition that grouping can only get you so far is correct. The advantage of the example you gave is that the two terms that you get from distributing $(x-2)$ over $(x^2+1)$, namely $(x^3-2x^2)$ and $(x-2)$, consist of distinct powers of $x$.

Comment: I would agree that in this case it is just a "lucky shot". In general I do believe that keeping formulas as simple and short as possible (thus grouping terms when they have a common factor) allows you to more easily find properties of this function, such as its factorization.

Comment: The RRT should _always_ be used when you want to factor polynomials by hand.